# How to construct a file path relative to another path?

Tags: c++, filesystems

Say my application is running from working directory A and ingests a config file in directory B (for which the absolute path is known). This config file will then reference other files either relative to the config file OR absolute (C). It doesn't have to be part of the same worktree.

For the sake of visualisation:

```
A (workdir)
├── config
│   └── default.yaml (B) --\
├── data                   | relative (or absolute) path to image (C)
│   └── image.png <--------/
├── tools
│   └── myapp.exe
│
```

How can I now normalize my paths C in relation to the working directory A? Or in other words, how can I make sure paths in C are rewritten in respect to A so that they refer to the same file when looked at by my running application in A? I want to use `std::filesystem` for that.

Comment: Use [std::relative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/relative)

Comment: @john How would I do that? I tried both way round but it doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: I'm just reading the documentation but this seems right to me `if (rsrc_path.is_relative()) rsrc_path = std::filesystem::relative(rsrc_path, config_path.parent_path());`

Comment: OK the above seems to leave the path relative to config_path, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `resourcePath` is absolute or relative, you might use [`operator/`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_slash) directly:

```
const auto final_absolute_path =
    std::filesystem::current_path() / "config" / resourcePath;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  path where is default.yaml                   path read from that file
```

Answer (score 3):

If your resource path is in `resourcePath` and your config file's path is `configPath` then you can just do:

```
if (resourcePath.is_relative())
{
  resourcePath = configPath.parent_path() / resourcePath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be working so far. Still I'm a bit scared of edge cases. What if the user does some fance "././path" stuff or something? Can I always rely on this?

Comment: yes, it should work. You can use `canonical` if you want to remove stray dots

Comment: Ok but in general those won't affect processing in the STL I guess? So if I do `std::ofstream("/some/./../././../weird/path/./to/file.txt")` that should also work?

Comment: yes, it should work

Comment: Not even need to check for relative, as `anypath / absolute_path == absolute_path`.

Comment: @Jarod42 You would append the absolute path to a relative one? How would that work? Isn't it the other way round?

Comment: @glades: See [`operator /=` doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append). It is the posix behavior BTW. i.e `path("/any/path") / path::("/bar") == path::("/bar")`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I see, thanks! Could you add this to the answer? Also funny how paths work in windows in this regard...